# Update MySQLi Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writing a website where users can enter files, and when they click delete, I don't want to actually delete it from my database. This is for reasons that are too complicated to explain on Stack Overflow.

Anyway, instead of having my query do delete, I am having it UPDATE.  I am running a server on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.  When I run the following code, I `var_dump` the query to the page so I can see it.  I then copy and pasted that query into phpMyAdmin, and it works fine.

However, when I just want to let the site run the query, it doesn't work.  Any advice?

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_query('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'syllashare');
$query = "UPDATE `uploads` SET `deleted`='yes' WHERE `id`=$id";
echo var_dump($query);
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
header('location: files.php');
```

Comment: May be database connection problem.

Comment: SQL injection prevention missed; you can use mysqli_error() for queries where problem is if any.

Comment: could it be possible that I'm not getting the permissions to use root?

Comment: You will see it if you use `or die (mysqli_error($connect));` after `mysqli_query(...)`

Comment: This question might be off-topic, since it is about accidentally using the wrong function, and so may not be of interest to the wider Stack Overflow audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't make a connection with `mysqli_query`, use [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) instead.

And beware of [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent this.

Comment: Yeah, I must've been typing to fast. Problem was I did mysqli_query instead of mysqli_connect. Thanks

Comment: thanks, can't believe i missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$connect = mysqli_query('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'syllashare');
```

I guess the function you are looking for here is `mysqli_connect()`, not `mysqli_query()`.

In addition...

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "UPDATE `uploads` SET `deleted`='yes' WHERE `id`=$id";
```

Never ever get something sent by the user and dump it in a SQL query. You are making your website vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). All user input must be treated some way or another. You can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), but since we are handling what I suppose to be a number, you should filter it with `intval()` instead.

Also, MySQLi supports [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), that helps making you code look cleaner, readable and meaningful, I suggest you use it. For instance:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'syllashare');

$query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `uploads` SET `deleted` = 'yes' WHERE `id` = ?");
$query->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: you know, mysqli_real_escape_string() won't be of *any* help here

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not done with my answer.

Comment: "[…] but since we are handling what I suppose to be a number, you should filter it with intval() instead." No, you can (and should) use a prepared statement for numbers, too, as you made clear in your example.

Comment: I meant in case you are not willing to use prepared statements.